# multiple funnel analysis with clickhouse in one query

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

So I am using windowfunnel() to do some funnel analysis, I came into this situation that I need to build several funnels with same event sequence but need to group by ids.
For example

```
windowfunnel(3600)(
ts,
event = 'click' and id = '1',
event = 'download' and id = '1'
) as levels
from tableA
```

but I actually need the funnels group by ids, so that I can have the 100 funnels with id from 1 to 100
is there any good way to do that in one query?

Thanks